# Simple SQL Being All Weird (To My Knowledge At Least)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this really simple piece of SQL that's misbehaving and for the life of me can't figure out why:
**Note:** It's actually within a stored procedure but this simplified version of it demonstrates the problem area.

```
declare @UserId int = 297;
declare @Password [RSNAME] = 'somepassword99';

begin try
if (@UserId > 0 and @Password <> '')
  begin
    update [User]
       set [Password] = @Password
     where UserId = @UserId;
    print(@@rowcount); --just to track changes
  end
end try
begin catch
  raiserror ('Error updating password!', 16, 1);
end catch;

if (@@rowcount <> 1)
begin
  print(@@rowcount); --just to track changes
  raiserror ('Error updating password! Zero or too many rows changed!', 16, 1);
end
```

> **On execution, I get this result:**
>
> **(1 row(s) affected)**
>
> **1 (this is the rowcount inside the if condition)**
>
> **0 (this is the rowcount outside the if condition)**
>
> **Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 20**
>
> **Error updating password! Zero or too many rows changed!**

If I were to place "if (@@rowcount <> 1)" section within the begin catch section, then all works fine. @@rowcount seems to be reset after altering the table?

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` is reset by *every* statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@@ROWCOUNT` is reset by each statement. You need to store `@@rowcount` in helper variable:

```
declare @UserId int = 297;
declare @Password [RSNAME] = 'somepassword99';
declare @rowcount INT = 0;

begin try
if (@UserId > 0 and @Password <> '')
  begin
    update [User]
       set [Password] = @Password
     where UserId = @UserId;

     select @rowcount = @@rowcount;
    print(@rowcount); --just to track changes
  end
end try
begin catch
  raiserror ('Error updating password!', 16, 1);
end catch;

if (@rowcount <> 1)
begin
  print(@rowcount); --just to track changes
  raiserror ('Error updating password! Zero or too many rows changed!', 16, 1);
end
```

Simple demo:

```
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2;

SELECT @@rowcount; -- 2

SELECT @@rowcount; -- 1
```

and:

```
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2;

PRINT(@@rowcount); -- Print 2

SELECT @@rowcount; -- 0
```